# Docker multistage: shared commands in subsequent stages

Tags: docker

I am trying to make a single multistage Dockerfile for production and dev images of my python app.
Currently I have 2 files, `Dockerfile.dev` and `Dockerfile.prod`. They are almost the same except few lines in the middle, the requirements section. With Dockerfile growing, it's comes really easy to miss something and hard to keep them in sync.

Ideally I what to get something like that:

```
FROM python as base_no_code_image
# install core dependencies
RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends git gcc && apt clean
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


FROM base_no_code_image as dev_no_code_image
# install dev specific deps, test suit, automated docs...
COPY ./requirements-dev.txt /app/requirements-dev.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements-dev.txt


FROM dev_no_code_image as dev_image
FROM base_no_code_image as prod_image
# docker instruction for dev_image *and* prod_image
ADD . /app
# expose the same ports, volumes, envs, entrypoint, cmd...

# with that listing, `dev_image` is same as `dev_no_code_image`, without `ADD . /app` and other stuff
```

Any ideas on how to achieve it? Or how I can rewrite it without repetings?

Comment: Can you make a precursor container that's used as the basis for both "branches"? Can you use build arguments via `ARG`? Remember, sometimes it's easier to express this in a shell script you can `RUN` instead of having to try and do everything in `Dockerfile`, like `RUN pip-installer.sh` where you've already set your `ARG` which that shell script can test.

Comment: @tadman 
"Can you make a precursor container that's used as the basis for both "branches"?" - yes, in this case it's `base_no_code_image`.

"Can you use build arguments via ARG?" - I think yes, but have no idea how it can help. I can be wrong, but docker has no option to "rerun" stage with different arg value.

Comment: It's not about re-running a stage, it's that you'd set up two build jobs with different args. Run the first, it'll make the intermediate container, then re-run with different args, so at least the intermediate part is already done.